# Responsive text across devices

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design, sass

I am working on the list of artists page of my lyrics website (a side project of mine). Here is what I currently have:

[image: artists list]

Notice how some artist names are long and so wrap onto two lines, and pushing my artist name block (the black background) up.

**CODE**

Here is the HTML markup:

```
<div class="row artists">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-6">
    <div class="artist-card">
      <div class="artist-image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="Rihanna" />
      </div>
      <div class="artist-info">
        <div class="artist-name">
          <h2>Rihanna</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- .artist-card -->
  <!-- more artist cards go here -->
</div><!-- .artists -->
```

And here is the Sass styles:

```
$artist-card-background-color: #bdbbb0;

.artist-card {
  position: relative;
  background-color: $artist-card-background-color;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;

  .artist-image {
    img {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }

  .artist-info {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);

    .artist-name {
      h2 {
        margin: 0;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px 15px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have also created a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Ciwan/pen/JOPPXR) to allow you guys to experiment with the cards and how they currently behave across various viewports.

**Question**

What is the cleanest way I can make the titles legible (readable), but also have the same height no matter what the viewport size is?

Comment: they stack up on eachother becuase the full string exeeds the limit of the block you are working in

Comment: this also depends on the screen size of users since this is dynamic as shown here. https://prnt.sc/h2avzv https://prnt.sc/h2aw4a

Comment: If you want it to always be static, then dont make your page dynamic or make all the blocks static, but that causes them to or stack on top of eachother or they will all exceed the page and line up in a 1 vertical row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Alternative 1**

Truncate the text if it exceeds the width.
Add this css to the H2:

```
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

**Alternative 2**

Use something like http://fittextjs.com/ or http://simplefocus.com/flowtype to change the font-size dynamically based on its length.

**Alternative 3**

Combine the 2 above, truncate the text only when the text gets to small to read.